# svelte router - how to change header depending on the route?

Tags: svelte

I use the svelte-routing - Router. What is the best way to change the header and footer depending on the route without putting it separate into every route? I am looking forward to all solutions, even if I have to change the router.

Comment: Which router are you using?

Comment: I use the svelte-routing - Router: https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing